# Arraylist and Arrays

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the difference between

```
ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>(100);
```

and

```
Object[] ar = new Object[100];
```

Is there any difference in the internal implementation i.e. the allocation in the memory?
Do both internally reserve 100 slots in the memory?

Comment: ArrayList is a dynamic array, similar to the c++ vector.
Any basic book will explain the differences.

Comment: I know what is the basic difference between the two what i was referring to was the internal implementation..have edited the question accordingly..

Comment: Why don't you write some sample code for each of the two; then use a debugger to see what's actually happening internally?

Answer (score 5):

An `ArrayList<Object>` holds a backing `Object[]`. The backing Array will be "resized" (a new array will be created and the old data will be copied over) if you would possibly overflow the size and additions are possible.

List implementations also provide additional methods to work on them.

Another thing is that you may use Generics(1.5) with Lists.

Comment: One thing not directly asked in the question is what happens with `ArrayList<SomeClassOtherThanObject>`. The internal array in that case is still an `Object[]`, not a `SomeClassOtherThanObject[]` due to erasure.

Comment: The backing array will be resized: Actually, since arrays cannot be resized, a new one will be created and the old data copied over.

Comment: @Thilo good point i added this. Before someone misunderstands the meaning.

Comment: Looks like i wasn't able to communicate what i wanted to with the question..what i would really like to know is new Arraylist(100) and new AnyArray[100] do both internally reserve 100 * Object size in the memory?

Comment: @hakish: Yes, they do. "100*Object size" is a bit unclear. They reserve an array with 100 slots for Objects (4 bytes or 8 bytes each, independent of the type of object). The actual objects are stored somewhere else on the heap, and nothing is reserved for that.

Comment: You mean 100 slots what will contain the address of the objects on the heap isn't it? So in that case isn't the memory reservation done for the main objects too?

Comment: Yes, 100 slots for object addresses. Initially all null. No memory is reserved for the main objects. They get reserved when created. The same object can also be pointed at by multiple slots at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

[ArrayList](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/java/j2se/1.6/p/java.util/c/ArrayList) is a [List](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/java/j2se/1.6/p/java.util/c/List)-implementation that uses a normal array internally to store and retrieve the objects added to list. The latter (Object[]) is a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

No, both does not mean same 
in `ArrayList < Object > al = new ArrayList< Object >(100);` just define initialCapacity in later you can add n number of elements
but in `Object[] ar = new Object[100];` you cannot add elements after 100 size

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList can grow or shrink dynamically at runtime, arrays cannot. ArrayList is a list implemented using an array. It gives you a variety of functions (list operations basically) which array doesn't provide.