# Performance or memory consumption difference between Array and ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I find that I can do almost any thing easily and with more control by using an `ArrayList` than by using an array in my day-to-day coding.
So I am asking:

1. Is it suitable to avoid arrays if I can use `ArrayList` instead?
2. Is there something I need to consider about memory when I replace an array with a `ArrayList`?

Comment: when you say list, are you talking about List interface ?

Comment: @ Kick Buttowski ex: ArrayList

Comment: Performance wise, adding and retrieving entries in array are quicker ( slightly). However, List provides more methods to manipulate its content. And also, as per Joshua Bloch in his `effective java`, he recommends the use of Lists over arrays basically because "Arrays and generics don't mix". No doubt, I will go with List.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8937560/476716

Comment: @Jimmy why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @Jimmy yes Please , make it an Answer.

Comment: its in answer. will be updating it soon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array or List in Java. Which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using one over another definitely impacts over performance and efficiency, though it might me very small. Also implementation of `JVM`  impacts a lot. However, adding and fetching entries from `arrays` are always quicker than in `List`.And if you are certain about the size of the `array` you need, you might be saving little memory too while using array.
However, `List` gives you more flexibility in modifying your contents, basically lots of methods to manipulate the data. It fully supports `generics`. 
Since arrays are `covariant`  and Generics are `invariant` , `Arrays and Generics don't mix` so `Joshua Bloch` recommends use of List over array in his book `Effective Java II` chapter 25.  I will definitely follow his advice and recommend you to use List as well instead of array.

Comment: Thank you !, I got a copy of Effective Java (2nd Edition), Seems a very good deal of JAVA knowledge. Thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: You are very welcome, and it is indeed a great book.

Answer (score 4):

When choosing specifically between an Array and an ArrayList, your first consideration should be whether the length of the container will need to change or not. If it does, use an ArrayList, but even if it doesn't, I would still go so far as to say that you should use an ArrayList. The reason for this is that the performance overhead incurred by using an ArrayList is generally not significant enough to warrant substituting it with an Array unless you absolutely know that performance is going to be an issue.

In general I would argue that it is a better idea to use a List over an Array in most situations. Arrays do offer slightly higher performance due to the reduced overhead. However, since List is an interface, there are a number of specific implementations available (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.) which gives you as well as the client code more flexibility.

For example, if you were to write a method that performs some computation and returns a List, the client code would only be able to assume that the List being returned is constructed in accordance to its definition in the Java documentation.

For example, in the client code you might find something like:

```
List<T> list = foo.getList();
```

If the method getList() currently returns an ArrayList, and you wanted to change its behaviour such that it now returns a LinkedList, you would be able to do that without worrying about breaking the client code which uses your method as it is only assuming that it will receive **some** implementation of a List but not any specific one.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList gives us many function which are not possible on simple arrays , we have to write big methods to things which we can do in one step in Arraylist.
So ArrayList requires more memory consumption than simple Arrays, but you can continue to use then in small programs that wont make much of a difference but when dealing with large ammout of data and performance issues, if you can go with simple arrays dont use ArrayList as Arrays are much faster.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is it suitable to avoid arrays if I can use List instead for the situation.

   There are some situations in which you may want to use an array over a list. I recommend you study "Big-O notation". Also, keep in mind that you can use a list and convert to an array by calling the `yourList.toArray(yourArray)` method. You can also do the opposite by using the `Arrays` class (`Arrays.asList(yourArray)`). For obvious reasons, using a `List` is more versatile than using an array, but if your dataset is small, it might be more efficient to use an array than a list.
2. Is there somethings I need to considered about memory when I replace an array with a List(use a list instead of an array).

   The most significant memory consideration you need to keep in mind is memory allocation. Once you create an array, you cannot grow or shrink its size. If you need an array of objects (let's say 100 items) that are 1M in size, until that array is garbage-collected, you have 100MB allocated for that object (array). With a list, if you want to remove or add an item, you can do so easily; thus reducing or increasing the list's memory footprint.

Comment: Can you answer more specifically wrt `ArrayList`?

Comment: @OrangeDog What specific details are you interested in?

Comment: If you are interested in more "Big-O" info, you can view this [cheat-sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

Comment: What qualifies as a small dataset?  I have a dataset with about 200 rows. Would you consider it as small or big?

Comment: @LuckMan I would consider that small. Search the web for benchmarks.